# Check if value loaded from Active Directory is null

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a project where data is loaded from an active directory. The data is then put into several fields and it generates a file. However not all the fields in the active directory will always be filled out, sometimes they may be blank. However I need it to still add something to the list of data I am generating so I can tell the form which fields to remove.

I am doing below, but it does not add `N/A` to my list. I tried searching around but the one answer I found didn't apply in this situation.

```
public List<String> SearchAD(String key)
        {
            List<String> data = new List<string>();

            DirectoryEntry dEntry = createDirectoryEntry();
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
            search.Filter = "(mailnickname=" + key + ")";

            string[] requiredProperties = new string[] { "****"};
            foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);

            SearchResult results = search.FindOne();
            if (results != null)
            {
                foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
                {
                    foreach (Object myCollection in results.Properties[property])
                        if (myCollection.ToString() == null)
                            data.Add("N/A");
                        else
                            data.Add(myCollection.ToString());

                }
            }

            return data;
        }
```

Comment: This will never be true: `if (myCollection.ToString() == null)` - try just `if (myCollection == null)`.

Comment: I tried that as well, the result is the same

Comment: Actually, that makes sense. You probably need something along the lines of `if (results.Properties[property].Count == 0) data.Add("N/A"); else foreach....`.

Comment: `results.Properties[property]`  returns a `ResultPropertyCollection`, which is a collection of `ResultPropertyValueCollection` items. Does your code above work as expected aside from not including the "N/A"? Because it seems to me that it isn't going deep enough to get a value, but I may be wrong (I've never used these objects, but was just looking through the docs).

Comment: @RufusL It works as expected.I am able to call this method and print out a list of the data, but the  "N/A" isn't there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that your code is otherwise working correctly, I'm guessing that `results.Properties[property]` returns an empty collection if `property` doesn't exist, so those properties are just getting skipped altogether (I could be wrong, though).

If this is the case, then I think the problem here is that we need to check if the collection contains the `property` or not first. If it doesn't, then add `"N/A"`, otherwise add the value:

```
foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
{
    if (results.Properties.Contains(property))
    {
        foreach (Object myCollection in results.Properties[property])
        {
            data.Add(myCollection.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        data.Add("N/A");
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! I guess I didn't consider it would skip null properties.